# Number on non-assigned array

Tags: c++

Given this code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int examplearray[] = {1,2,3};
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        cout << examplearray[i] << "\t";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I have the following output:
    1       2       3       3       4200928 6422336

I am pretty sure this is answered somewhere, but I have been browsing Google for a while and I can't find an explanation for this. I haven't defined a value for the 4th and 5th positions of the array, and I assumed it's value would be 0 or NULL . Why do they have random values?

I noticed this when I was trying to make a code like this:

```
for(int i = 0; examplearray[i] != 0; /* while it's not empty */i++){
    /* do something */
}
```

How can I do something like I wanted to do on this code?

Comment: You're reading off the end of the array which yields undefined behaviour, you're just reading out garbage values that happen to be there in memory

Comment: _and I assumed it's value would be 0 or NULL_: your assumption is wrong. The array has a length of 3 and you are reading beyond the en of the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `int examplearray[] = {1,2,3};`, the length of the array is not specified explicitly, then will be determined according to the intializer list; the result is `3`. So trying to access the 4-6th elements (which don't exist at all) is undefined behavior.

If you suppose the length of array is `6` you should write `int examplearray[6] = {1,2,3};`. For this case the remaining elements would be initialized as `0`.

Comment: Okay so now when I define a bigger size for the array i get 0 from the undefined elements of the array. This was what I was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you trying to access array index out of bound, It's **undefined behaviors** in `C` and `C++`. It means there's no guarantee as to what will happen.